# Is the string type a scalar, and if so why?

Tags: c++, c, string, scalar

A few websites claim that the string type is a scalar. As I understand it, scalars are single-value types, as opposed to array types. But isn't a string essentially an array of chars? So why would it be a scalar?

EDIT: If the answer/explanation differs from C to C++, I'd like explanations to include both languages. I'm adding the C++ tag to this question.

Comment: Reference for context please? Technically, C does not *have* a string type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`char*` and `const char*` are scalar types, whereas `char[n]` and `const char[n]` are not.

> Arithmetic types, enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types, `std::nullptr_t`, and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called *scalar types*. (3.9 Types [basic.types] §9)

Answer (score 6):

The distinction between scalar and aggregate types is fuzzy.  A 32-bit integer is also a  container of 32 bits. Even though a string is technically an aggregate of characters, we often manipulate them as we would manipulate scalars.  We treat them as immutable, compare them, pass them as arguments, etc.  In C the aggregate nature of strings is more apparent, but many other languages including C++ make them feel like scalars.

Other examples of the fuzziness are complex numbers and 3D vectors.  They are really made up of several `doubles`, but numerical programs still allocate them on the stack, pass them by value, overload scalar operators on them, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, all basic primitive data types are considered scalar.

However, because C++ has a STL which is part of the language, you can consider a string (NOT a char array) to be a scalar type.

in C, there's no such string primitive (because the definition of a string in C is in essence a array of scalar char types) so it all depends how you're looking at it.

Comment: The notion of "scalar types" is very specific to C++, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

In C a string is a data format and not a type. A C string is of type array `N+1` of  `char` where `N` is the length of the string. Array types are not a part of the scalar types but of the aggregate types.

C++ also has a `string` type which is of a class type but which is not part of the scalar types.